# Create Report Subscription on SSRS from C# using E-mail delivery

Tags: c#, email, reporting-services

I want to mimic the data-driven subscription of SQL Server Enterprise edition on SQL Server Standard edition by creating a C# program to loop through the recipient list and create a subscription that will pass in the parameters for their report, and e-mail it to them.

I can find most of what I need, but nowhere do I see how to set e-mail delivery as the delivery mechanism.

I can create the `DeliverySettings.Extension` to "Report Server Email" because it is a property of the subscription, which I can't create without that setting because I get an error saying

> An attempt has been made to use a delivery extension that is not registered for this report server.

I know e-mail is a configured delivery option because I can create an e-mail subscription manually.

Comment: We finally got Enterprise edition, and I am in love with Data-Driven Subscriptions. I just wish there were some sort of template system available. I make very similar subscriptions for different reports, and I have to do everything from scratch every time.